# I am writing 3DES (using SHA1 HASH) encryption algorithm using C #. Key size error

Tags: sha1, 3des

I am writing 3DES (using SHA1 HASH) encryption algorithm using C #. 
Size error in tdes.Key = keyArray of the following code. I do not know what went wrong.

public static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, bool useHashing)

{

```
 byte[] keyArray;
 byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

 System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader = new AppSettingsReader();


 // Get the key from config file

 string key = (string)settingsReader.GetValue("SecurityKey", typeof(String));

 //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(key);
 if (useHashing)
  {

   SHA1CryptoServiceProvider objSHA1CryptoService = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
   keyArray = objSHA1CryptoService.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
   objSHA1CryptoService.Clear();

  }
  else
        keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
        tdes.Clear();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
    }
```

}

Comment: I solved this problem myself.

Comment: To achieve the same result as this code, I wrote C ++ code as below, but the result of encryption is different. What is the problem?